# Linux task scheduler with GUI

Tags: linux, user-interface, scheduled-tasks

I know this might be deemed a bad question, but it could save me a load of programming, so I hope not...

Basically, I'm wondering if anyone has any strong recommendations of job schedulers that can run either Oracle stored procedures, Java apps, or both.  The other pre-requisite is that it comes with a nice web-based admin GUI out of the box, allowing you to configure new jobs, schedule/request these, and see their statuses, failures, next run times, etc.

[Obsidian](http://carfey.com/) came really close on paper, but once I got it up and running properly, it kept complaining about no licences (even though I'd taken the no licence option), and just didn't run anything.  Maybe I can fix that tomorrow, but I'd probably prefer to go true open source anyway.

I've seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software (and I might take a look at Open Source Job Scheduler), but I'm wondering if anyone could save me more time and effort with a good starting point?

Thanks.

Comment: How about just good ole crontab with corntab (http://www.corntab.com/) on top?

Comment: Ta.  I did think about something like that (or writing something to sit on top of cron myself), but I want the previous run history in there too.  Yeah, displaying the cron log isn't that hard, but this is for a really quick proof of concept, so a configurable bit of software that ticks all boxes (and potentially more...) straight away would probably be best.

Answer (score 2):

Would [Webmin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ScheduledCommands) be good enough for you?

Comment: The OP asked for a web-based GUI that handles task scheduling. Webmin does that. That is the definition of providing an answer - particularly to an off-topic (and long since closed) question.